# Is it possible to create a tezos address without paying a fee to do so, or revealing which address paid for the fee?

Tags: address, reuse

Is it possible to create a tezos address without paying a fee to do so, or revealing which address paid for the fee?

I am curious about this because address reuse and every new address having to be associated with an address that paid for it's creation, seemingly makes the network privacy more vulnerable to forensic analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Any tezos address can *receive* transactions without revealing. When an address takes any active action on the chain, it must be revealed, and a fee must be paid for revelation. This fee is burnt immediately and not collected by any other address.  This was introduced in the Babylon protocol to prevent address creation spam as with more addresses in use, the larger the blockchain storage becomes bloated with emptiness.

Any address can reveal any address and pay the burn fee, provided you have the private keys to both addresses. ie: address A can reveal and pay the burn for address B. Keep in mind that the revelation operation will contain the fact that A paid for B's reveal.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: @RadixCapital Great. Please mark as answered.